# SQL issue - type of fkey

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL

## What I need

In SELECT query I need to select owner_type (client or domain). If solution does not exist please help me to rework this schema.

### Schema (tables)

1. Albums - id | client_id (fkey) | domain_id (fkey) | name
2. Clients - id | first_name | last_name
3. Domains - id | name

Description: Albums owner can be Client ***or*** Domain ***or*** future other Nodes...

#### 1. CREATE TABLE QUERY

```
CREATE TABLE albums 
  ( 
     id        BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
     client_id BIGINT, 
     domain_id BIGINT, 
     name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES clients(id), 
     FOREIGN KEY (domain_id) REFERENCES domains(id), 
     CHECK ((client_id IS NULL) <> (domain_id IS NULL)) 
  );
```

#### 2. SELECT QUERY

```
SELECT albums.id, 
       albums.name, 
       COALESCE(c.id, d.id) AS owner_id 
FROM   albums 
       LEFT JOIN clients c 
              ON albums.client_id = c.id 
       LEFT JOIN domains d 
              ON albums.domain_id = d.id
```

Need something like -> if c.id === null -> owner_type = 'Domain'

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, 
       COALESCE(c.id, d.id) AS owner_id,
       (CASE WHEN c.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'client' ELSE 'domain' END) as owner_type
FROM albums a LEFT JOIN
     clients c 
     ON a.client_id = c.id LEFT JOIN
     domains d 
     ON a.domain_id = d.id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need two separate columns representing `client_id` and `domain_id` for the type of owners? It seems that if you were to add more nodes, you would have to add additional columns.

Could you have an `owners` table representing all types of owners, and have an `owner_id` foreign key on the `albums` table?

I was thinking something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE albums ( 
    id    BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    owner_id    BIGINT,
    name    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES owners(id)
);

CREATE TABLE owners ( 
        id    BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
        type    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        name    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );
```

You could then query for albums belonging to clients:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, o.name AS owner_name
FROM albums a
JOIN owners o ON o.id = a.owner_id
WHERE o.type = 'Client';
```

As new nodes (types of owners) are added, you simply need to add them to the `owners` table without modifying the schema of the `albums` table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok but I need some foreign keys in owners table. In short this IDs must exist (clientId, domainId...).